# Ant Design notification does not support translation component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use formatted messages (translation component) in the Ant notification "notification.error" component. However in the format I am using this is returning the error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn3yb.png)

I ask for help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a React Component, use the `formatMessage`

```
description: intl.formatMessage({
  id: 'deposits.wiretransfer.errormessage2',
})....
```